# How do I hide multiple reply buttons in a comment section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic chat app in which I am trying to add a functionality of a user being able to reply to a particular comment. Each unique comment has a reply button next to it via which a reader can reply to it.

Now the requirements are;

1. A text field should appear ONLY in the place of the reply button
   which was clicked along with a ok button.
2. When the user clicks on a particular reply button requirement (1)
   should be fulfilled but then immediately clicks on another reply
   button then the previous text box and ok button should disappear
   from the previous position and instead should appear in front of the
   current clicked reply button hence fulling requirement (1) in the
   process again.

It would be great that solution is in Javascript without the use of any library but if it can't be helped then I am open to a jQuery solution as well.

The code I have written is only allowing me to perform this action for the first comment and does not work for the remaining comments. Ignore the {{ }} nomenclature as that's Django syntax. Where am I going wrong with my code?

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("reply").addEventListener('click', function(event){
document.getElementById("reply").style.display = 'none';
var ok = document.createElement("BUTTON");
ok.innerHTML = 'OK';
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type ='text';
input.name = "comment";
input.style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(input);
document.getElementById('myForm').appendChild(ok);
event.preventDefault();
  });
}

</script>

</head>

<div class="margin clb">
<h2>comment 1</h2>
<form id ="myForm" method='POST' action="{% url 'some_url' %}" aria-live="polite">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button  id= "reply" type="submit" class="rep btn bcg bm mts mbl">reply</button>
    <br>
</form>

<h2>comment 2</h2>
<form id ="myForm" method='POST' action="{% url 'skin_doctor_price' %}" aria-live="polite">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id= "reply" type="submit" class="rep btn bcg bm mts mbl">reply</button>
    <br>

</form>

<h2>comment 3</h2>
<form id ="myForm" method='POST' action="{% url 'skin_doctor_price' %}" aria-live="polite">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id= "reply" type="submit" class="rep btn bcg bm mts mbl">reply</button>
    <br>

</form>

<h2>comment 4</h2>
<form id ="myForm" method='POST' action="{% url 'skin_doctor_price' %}" aria-live="polite">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id= "reply" type="submit" class="rep btn bcg bm mts mbl">reply</button>
    <br>

</form>

<h2>comment 5</h2>
<form id ="myForm" method='POST' action="{% url 'skin_doctor_price' %}" aria-live="polite">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button id= "reply" type="submit" class="rep btn bcg bm mts mbl">reply</button>
    <br>

</form>
</div>

<br><br>

{% endblock %}
```